# @RequestMapping not redirecting to the specified URL : Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am trying to create a sample spring boot application which can connect to postgres. But I am not able to redirect to the path specified in the rest controller. The code for my project is given below:
pom.xml

```
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.vmware.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBootSample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootDemo1</name>
    <description>Sample project for Spring Eureka</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
          <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
          <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

application.properties

```
server.port=3000

spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/local_db
spring.datasource.data-username=postgres
spring.datasource.data-password=postgres

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

SpringBootExampleApplication.java

```
package org.kumar.springboot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

import org.kumar.spring.enitiy.Employee;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
public class SpringBootExampleApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootExampleApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

EmployeeController.java

```
package org.kumar.spring.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import org.kumar.spring.enitiy.Employee;
import org.kumar.spring.repository.EmployeeRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/data")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getEmployees(){
        return (List<Employee>)employeeRepository.findAll();
    }


}
```

Employee.java

```
package org.kumar.spring.enitiy;

public class Employee {

    private String employeeId;
    private String employeeName;

    public String getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    public void setEmployeeId(String employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }
    public String getEmployeeName() {
        return employeeName;
    }
    public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [employeeId=" + employeeId + ", employeeName=" + employeeName + "]";
    }
    public Employee(String employeeId, String employeeName) {
        super();
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.employeeName = employeeName;
    }

}
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
package org.kumar.spring.repository;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import org.kumar.spring.enitiy.Employee;

public interface EmployeeRepository extends CrudRepository<Employee, String>
{

}
```

I am trying to run the following:
Request : GET http://localhost:3000/data/employees
Response :

```
 {
  "timestamp": 1492152367659,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "No message available",
  "path": "/data/employees"
}
```

What mistake am I committing.

Comment: does your app even starts? `Employee` should be an entity and needs an Id. Everything else looks ok.

Comment: also add `spring.data.rest.base-path=/api` value to the application properties. [this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-rest) may be a good place to get started.

Comment: The log file should give you the list of mapped urls (lines like `o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestHandlerMapping   : Mapped "{[/data/employees],methods=...`); what do you see?

Comment: @saket0207 Did my answer work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, your `EmployeeController` class has n**ot been detected/scanned by the Spring container** because of the classes are in **different package hierarchy** and the container has not been instructed to scan in which package to look for.

So there are two options to solve the issue:

(1) Change your `SpringBootExampleApplication` class package to `org.kumar.spring`

(2) Add `@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.kumar.spring"})`

I suggest you prefer the option(1) above otherwise, for option(2), you need to add `@EnableJpaRepositories` to make the program to work from end to end (i.e., connecting to the database using your `EmployeeRepository` class).